# Desktop based project management/organizer for Linux?

Tags: linux, open-source, project-management, desktop-client

I need a really simple project manager for Linux (Lubuntu). I want to track to-do items, bugs, etc; and I also need to organize all the tasks in a Gantt diagram.

Currently I'm using a plain txt file and well, I want something more powerful/complex. I've checked all the other questions tagged [project-management](/questions/tagged/project-management), but they're talking about web-based software – but I prefer desktop applications.

Which application can you recommend?

Comment: Pretty much all FOSS alternatives to Microsoft Project are unusably buggy or clunky or both. IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend [TaskWarrior](http://taskwarrior.org/). The core is command-line based, but there are also other frontends.

You might be interested in these two frontends:

- [tchart](https://github.com/grovesteyn/tchart), a frontend which can do GANTT style diagrams, and
- [ptask](http://wpitchoune.net/blog/ptask/), a GTK based frontend.

I though haven't used these two frontends, just the TUI frontend named [vit](http://tasktools.org/projects/vit.html).